# Handle onClick event with Databinding and MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I want to set an `onClickListener` on an `ImageView` using `Databinding` and control it from `ViewModel(MVVM)`.

In the xml layout all things that I've implemented with `Databinding` works. But onClick event is not working.

I get this error:

> error:cannot find symbol

**XML:**

```xml
<data>
    <variable
        name="photo"
        type="learn.app.papewall.model.Photo" />
    <variable
        name="viewModelDetail"
        type="learn.app.papewall.view.detail.DetailViewModel" />
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.detail.DetailFragment">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:onClick="@{viewModelDetail.save()}"
        app:imageUrl="@{photo.urls.regular}"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:text="@{photo.user.name}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun save(photo: Photo){
    setWallpaper(photo, false)
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
viewModel.save(photoObj!!)
```

I don't know what is this error. I tried solutions from stackoverflow but none of them solved my  problem.

I want to set `onClick` Listener using `Databinding` and `MVVM` any solutions would be appreciate I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try modifying your onClickListener as follows: 
`android:onClick="@{() -> viewModelDetail.save(photo)}"`

Comment: Thank you this worked. The problem was that I didn't put the photo object and this "() ->", this thing I don't really know what means.

Comment: `() -> foo()` is a lambda expression taking no arguments and calling `foo()` when invoked

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the photo to the `save` function, like that

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModelDetail.save(photo)}"
```

Comment: This method doesn't work. I had to add "() -> " for the **onClick** function. Thank you anyway

Comment: You can have a look here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture

Comment: @android if you had a v:View in your function as parameters then you wouldn't need to write the ()-> part, but because your function don't have the same signature as the onClick method you call your function from the onClick function